# What does the "static" modifier after "import" mean?

Tags: java, modifier, static-import

When used like this:

```
import static com.showboy.Myclass;

public class Anotherclass{}
```

what's the difference between `import static com.showboy.Myclass` and `import com.showboy.Myclass`?

Answer (score 416, accepted):

See [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)

> The static import declaration is
>   analogous to the normal import
>   declaration. Where the normal import
>   declaration imports classes from
>   packages, allowing them to be used
>   without package qualification, the
>   static import declaration imports
>   static members from classes, allowing
>   them to be used without class
>   qualification.
>
> So when should you use static import?
>   Very sparingly! Only use it when you'd
>   otherwise be tempted to declare local
>   copies of constants, or to abuse
>   inheritance (the Constant Interface
>   Antipattern). In other words, use it
>   when you require frequent access to
>   static members from one or two
>   classes. If you overuse the static
>   import feature, it can make your
>   program unreadable and unmaintainable,
>   polluting its namespace with all the
>   static members you import. Readers of
>   your code (including you, a few months
>   after you wrote it) will not know
>   which class a static member comes
>   from. Importing all of the static
>   members from a class can be
>   particularly harmful to readability;
>   if you need only one or two members,
>   import them individually. Used
>   appropriately, static import can make
>   your program more readable, by
>   removing the boilerplate of repetition
>   of class names.

Comment: I completely agree with the warnings above by @xsl. One area where it's definitely very useful is for junit's Assert: _import static org.junit.Assert.*_ for all your unit tests.

Comment: -- for control pasting very long and not really eye-catching documentation file, instead of writing simple explaination.

Comment: @xsl Is the lower part of the post supposed to be in a quote block? it looks like you typed it.

Comment: @Ferrybig: It's a quote from the linked documentation.

Comment: It's like [`include`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318144/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-require-in-ruby#318170) in Ruby!

Comment: Just simply pasting a snippet from documentation doesn't seem to me as a proper answer here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 252):

There is no difference between those two imports you state.  You can, however, use the static import to allow unqualified access to static members of other classes.  Where I used to have to do this:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
      .
      .
      .
if (StringUtils.isBlank(aString)) {
      .
      .
      .
```

I can do this:

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isBlank;
      .
      .
      .
if (isBlank(aString)) {
      .
      .
      .
```

You can see more in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html).

Answer (score 60):

Static import is used to import static fields / method of a class instead of:

```
package test;

import org.example.Foo;

class A {

 B b = Foo.B_INSTANCE;

}
```

You can write :

```
package test;

import static org.example.Foo.B_INSTANCE;

class A {

 B b = B_INSTANCE;

}
```

It is useful if you are often used a constant from another class in your code and if the static import is not ambiguous.

Btw, in your example "import static org.example.Myclass;" won't work : import is for class, import static is for static members of a class.

Answer (score 40):

The basic idea of static import is that whenever you are using a static class,a static variable or an enum,you can import them and save yourself from some typing.

I will elaborate my point with example.

```
import java.lang.Math;

class WithoutStaticImports {

 public static void main(String [] args) {
  System.out.println("round " + Math.round(1032.897));
  System.out.println("min " + Math.min(60,102));
 }
}
```

Same code, with static imports:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

class WithStaticImports {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    out.println("round " + round(1032.897));
    out.println("min " + min(60,102));
  }
}
```

**Note**: static import can make your code confusing to read.

Comment: Would it mean anything to write `import static java.lang.Math` without the asterisk?

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius nope, import static is only for static members of a class.

Comment: Good answer! Since many 'newbies' read this post one should however give one little warning: **Do not overuse the asterisk** to prevent namespace pollution.

Answer (score 24):

> the difference between "import static com.showboy.Myclass" and "import com.showboy.Myclass"?

The first should generate a compiler error since the static import only works for importing fields or member types. (assuming MyClass is not an inner class or member from showboy)

I think you meant

```
import static com.showboy.MyClass.*;
```

which makes all static fields and members from MyClass available in the actual compilation unit without having to qualify them... as explained above

Answer (score 16):

The `import` allows the java programmer to access classes of a package without package qualification.

The `static import` feature allows to access the static members of a class without the class qualification.

The `import` provides accessibility to classes and interface whereas `static import` provides accessibility to static members of the class.

**Example :**

With ***import***

```
import java.lang.System.*;    
class StaticImportExample{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  

       System.out.println("Hello");
       System.out.println("Java");  

  }   
}
```

With ***static import***

```
import static java.lang.System.*;    
class StaticImportExample{  
  public static void main(String args[]){  

   out.println("Hello");//Now no need of System.out  
   out.println("Java");  

 }   
}
```

See also : [What is static import in Java 5](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/10/what-is-static-import-in-java-5-example-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 3):

Say you have static fields and methods inside a class called `MyClass` inside a package called `myPackage` and you want to access them  directly  by typing    `myStaticField` or `myStaticMethod` without typing each time `MyClass.myStaticField` or `MyClass.myStaticMethod`.

Note : you need to do an
   `import myPackage.MyClass`  or `myPackage.*`
    for accessing the other resources

Answer (score 1):

The `static` modifier after `import` is for retrieving/using static fields of a class. One area in which I use `import static` is for retrieving constants from a class.
We can also apply `import static` on static methods. Make sure to type `import static` because `static import` is wrong.

**[What is `static import` in Java - JavaRevisited](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/10/what-is-static-import-in-java-5-example-tutorial.html)**  - A very good resource to know more about `import static`.