# How does Rails Plugin Storage work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Trying to figure out how to install rails plugins manually on windows so I have a few questions.

1. What does the directory need to be named in vendor/plugins?  Is it arbitrary or is it linked to something within the plugin config files or is that what you set in the environment.rb?
2. Once I've copied the files to the correct directory, do I always need to run something inside like init.rb or is it good to go?
3. What's the difference between 'require' and 'include'?

Thanks!

Comment: the third question is more about ruby not ruby-on-rails. It's better if you made another question with that

Comment: It might help is you named the plugins you want to install. This way you would get more concrete examples.

Comment: egarcia: i'm just looking for theory in general that shouldn't have to apply to specific plugins?  I'm just looking for strategies in general for installing plugins manually without using script/plugin install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - What does the directory need to be named in vendor/plugins? Is it arbitrary or is it linked to something within the plugin config files or is that what you set in the environment.rb?

Depends on your definition of "need". In theory the plugin directories could be called `plugin1`, `plugin2`, `plugin3` etc. But for the sake of your own sanity, it is better that they are named after the plugin they host, so the `will_paginate` plugin should be inside the `vendor/plugins/will_paginate` directory and so on.

If they are hosted on github, the folders will be called the same way as the github project.

Normally all plugins will have a `init.rb` file on their "root folder" : `vendor/plugins/will_paginate/init.rb`. That's how you can know that you put the right files on the right path. They also usually (not allways) have a `lib` directory inside them: `vendor/plugins/will_paginate/lib/*`

> - Once I've copied the files to the correct directory, do I always need to run something inside like init.rb or is it good to go?

You don't need to run `init.rb` yourself, but it neither exactly "good to go": You have to re-start the web server. When initializing, rails goes through the `vendor/plugins/*` directories, calling the `init.rb` files itself.

> - What's the difference between 'require' and 'include'?

That's a completely different question. Besides, it is already answered on StackOverflow. So I hope you don't mind if I point you to the [already existing question & its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318144/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-require-in-ruby).

> - I'm just looking for strategies in general for installing plugins manually without using script/plugin install

The simplest way is actually installing git on windows. This can be done with [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/).

Then your `script/plugin install` will probably work. If it doesn't you can install the plugin yourself using `git clone`. Here's an example with a random github plugin:

```
cd vendor/plugins
git clone git://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on.git
```

This will create the plugin folder just like `script/plugin install` would. Just don't forget to cd to the `vendor/plugins` folder first.

If you can't/don't want to use git, then github has a 'download as a zip' link on the top of each project. I guess you can download the plugins as zips and them uncompress them on the right places.

I hope this helps.