# What is difference between require and include?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between include and require in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318144/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-require-in-ruby)

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'load_test_data.rb')
require 'find'
require 'fileutils'

include CommonValidators
```

Can someone please give me proper example to understand the difference between `require` and `include`?

Comment: Krunal, can you please remember to make code look like code by indenting it or using backticks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an excellent answer to this here:
[What is the difference between include and require in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318144/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-require-in-ruby/318170#318170)