# Do I need to call the Math class directly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I'm using a function from the Math module, such as log10, do I need to call `Math.log10(number)` or can I do `number.log10`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers have no `log10` method available by default, but you can extend the `Numeric` class to add that functionality:

```
class Numeric

  def log10
    Math.log10 self
  end
end

10.log10
=> 1.0
```

If you just want to use the methods without having to write `Math` all the time, you could `include Math`, then you can call `log10` directly:

```
class YourClass
  include Math

  def method n
    log10 n
  end
end

YourClass.new.method 10
=> 1.0
```

Comment: You don't need to require Math to use it.

Comment: @Justin: please take a look at the difference between include and require here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318144/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-require-in-ruby :)

Comment: @Justin, I think I misunderstood your question. Please take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just try, using irb for instance? or just this command line:

```
ruby -e 'puts Math.log10(10)'
```

> 1.0

```
ruby -e 'log10(10)'
```

> -e:1:in `<main>': undefined method`log10' for main:Object
>   (NoMethodError)

I guess you have your answer :)

By the way you can include the Math module:

```
include Math
```

to be able to use your log10 method without writing it explicitly everytime:

```
 ruby -e 'include Math; puts log10(10)'
  => 1.0
```