# Need some nice explanation on these code snippets - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The First One

```
module A
  include B
  def initialize
     -----
  end
  def x
    ---------
    self << Y.new     # I need some explanation on this please
    --------
  end
end
```

The Second One is

```
class H
  include G
  include F

  EE = [.,.,.,]
  def << k     # I need some explanation here
    k.id?
    -------
  end
end
```

Can some one please help me out! I am a newbie to the whole kind of programming

Comment: k is a argument. Y is a calss. Thanks

Comment: I found an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318144/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-require-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both instances the `<<` is being used as an operator.

`self << Y.new` is equivalent to `self.send(:'<<', Y.new)` so for instance if self was an [Array](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/%3C%3C), this would push Y.new into it.

In the second example you are defining the operator `<<` and `k` is the argument .

Comment: So, after pushing will it go to the next step of the same method??

Comment: it is a method just like any other. In the case of array it is an alias for `push`. So, yes. See this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm) for more info on operators.