# access scope of 'required' files to get variables

Tags: ruby

If I `require 'helper_file'` in a program and there are constants and variables declared in that required file is there a way to access those variables and constants?

`require 'helper_file'`

`...some nice code`

`x = ConstantFromRequireFile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use require to load a library into your Ruby program. It will return true if successful.

So you have a file *example.rb*:

```
require 'library.rb'

# Some code

x = CONSTANTFROMREQUIREFILE

puts x # "Hello World"

method_from_required_file # "I'm a method from a required file."
```

and a file *library.rb*:

```
CONSTANTFROMREQUIREFILE = "Hello World"

def method_from_required_file
  puts "I'm a method from a required file."
end
```

As you can see you access the constant and the method as you would access a constant and a method from the same file.

You can read more about require here: [What is the difference between include and require in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318144/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-require-in-ruby) and here: [Kernal Module in Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require)

Answer (score 2):

constants, global variables, instance variables and class variables defined in the top level scope in a required file will all be available in the scope of the requiring file, but local variables will not. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: That answers the question. I was mistaken about what comes into scope. Thank you.