# How does include Module work?

Tags: ruby

```
module A
end 

class Klass
  include A
end
```

How does this include influence Klass? Does it simply put Klass into module A or do something more?

Comment: It does not work. It is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: If you have some methods inside your module and you use `include` in a class, those methods can be used in the class.

```
Module A
  def shout
    puts "HEY THERE!!!!"
  end
end 

class Klass
  include A
end 

# Create instance of Klass
instance = Klass.new

# Produces "HEY THERE!!!!"    
instance.shout
```

Answer (score 1):

> The include method takes all the methods from another module and
>   includes them into the current module. This is a language-level thing
>   as opposed to a file-level thing as with require. The include method
>   is the primary way to "extend" classes with other modules (usually
>   referred to as mix-ins). For example, if your class defines the method
>   "each", you can include the mixin module Enumerable and it can act as
>   a collection. This can be confusing as the include verb is used very
>   differently in other languages.

from here: [What is the difference between include and require in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318144/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-require-in-ruby)

also take a look at this page: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html it has a verbose explanation about how include works.

Answer (score 1):

`include` is one of the ways to include methods of a Module in another Module or Class.

Please read [my article](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1149/understanding-method-lookup-in-ruby-20) on how that affects method calls in Ruby/

Comment: That link seems to be broken @Marc-AndréLafortune is the article available at an alternate location?

Comment: Argh. Got a transfer that to my blog then. You can use this one: https://web.archive.org/web/20141112151444/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1149/understanding-method-lookup-in-ruby-20