# Require in an IRB shell

Tags: ruby, require, irb

I'm working in an IRB shell on a dos CMD

I load a module from a mystuff file 
require '.\mystuff'

I change the module in the mystuff file and I type again
require '.\mystuff'

How come the IRB does not pick up the changes in the file when I try to call functions or variables from the newest version of my mystuff module?

Comment: you can load a module using include 'MyModule' :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` will not load the same file twice. If you want to load the file again, you need to use `load`. See [What is the difference between include and require in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318144/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-require-in-ruby) for more information.

Comment: You also need to add the file type when using `load`, so `require '.\mystuff'` corresponds to `load '.\mystuff.rb'`.

Answer (score -2):

### Your Syntax is Wrong

Ruby doesn't use backslashes. You need to use forward slashes, or use [File#join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-join).

### Your $LOAD_PATH is Wrong

Your `$LOAD_PATH` (a.k.a `$:`) is wrong. You need to include the present working directory with:

```
$: << '.'
```

in irb, or use [Kernel#require_relative](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative) in executable or sourced files.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using backslashes in Ruby file paths. Ruby is happy with either.

Comment: @Borodin The backslash is an escape character. If it works for you, great, but it's generally the cause of a great number of easily-fixed problems.

Comment: The OP is using a single-quoted string, so a backslash is not treated as an escape character here. The load path must be right, or else the first `require` call would have failed.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall You appear to be making unwarranted assumptions. There is no properly-formatted executable code listed by the OP, nor does the OP state that there *aren't* error messages. Please feel free to add your own answer after making your own assumptions about the thoroughness or correctness of the original post.

Comment: @CodeGnome There is 100% valid code in the original post. Just because they didn’t use code formatting doesn’t mean it’s wrong. And “does not pick up changes when [calling methods]” means the methods do work, thus the `$LOAD_PATH` was set right. Your making assumptions that there *were* errors.