# Rspec - difference between config.include and require?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm going through the Rails Tutorial and I noticed that [it recommends including Capybara](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#code-capybara_dsl) via `config.include Capybara::DSL` in `spec_helper.rb`, whereas the [Capybara readme](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec) recommends adding `require 'capybara/rspec'` to `spec_helper.rb`.

I know the [technical difference between `include` and `require`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318144/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-require-in-ruby), but what's the practical difference between using `config.include` and `require` in `spec_helper.rb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the contents of `capybara/rspec` (e.g. [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rspec.rb#L8) on Github), you will see it that it also calls `config.include Capybara::DSL`, but it also does some other setup (e.g. making sure Capybara sessions are reset after running specs, switching to the JS driver if necessary etc.).

I think you should go with what the Capybara README says and require `capybara/rspec` so that you are less exposed to potential changes in the way Capybara hooks into RSpec.

Comment: Thanks! I had taken a look at `capybara/rspec`, but I didn't notice the `Rspec.configure` block for some reason. Much appreciated.