# How do I write a helper for an integration test in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing

How do I write an integration test helper that is used amongst several integration tests? I've tried the following with the following errors. I'm considering making a base class and extending that, but I don't understand how 'test_helper' is working! I can't put the helper methods in test_helper because they use special integration helpers like `post_with_redirect`.

#### LS

```
$ ls test/integration
integration_helper_test.rb  post_integration_test.rb  user_flows_test.rb
```

#### Code, integration_helper_test.rb

```
class IntegrationHelperTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def login(user)
    ...
```

#### Code, post_integration_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'integration_helper_test'
# require 'integration/integration_helper_test'

class PostIntegrationTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # include IntegrationHelperTest
```

#### Error

```
$ rake
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- integration_helper_test
C:/Users/Chloe/workspace/SeenIt/test/integration/post_integration_test.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => test:run => test:integration
```

#### Code, post_integration_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
# require 'integration_helper_test'
require 'integration/integration_helper_test'

class PostIntegrationTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
```

#### Error

```
  1) Error:
PostIntegrationTest#test_should_create_post:
NoMethodError: undefined method `login' for #<PostIntegrationTest:0x3da81d0>
    test/integration/post_integration_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:PostIntegrationTest>'
```

#### Code, post_integration_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
# require 'integration_helper_test'
#require 'integration/integration_helper_test'

class PostIntegrationTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include IntegrationHelperTest
```

#### Error

```
$ rake
rake aborted!
wrong argument type Class (expected Module)
C:/Users/Chloe/workspace/SeenIt/test/integration/post_integration_test.rb:6:in `include'
C:/Users/Chloe/workspace/SeenIt/test/integration/post_integration_test.rb:6:in `<class:PostIntegrationTest>'
C:/Users/Chloe/workspace/SeenIt/test/integration/post_integration_test.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => test:run => test:integration
```

#### test_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick one:

```
module IntegrationHelperTest 
  # ...
end

require 'test_helper'
require 'integration/integration_helper_test'
class PostIntegrationTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include IntegrationHelperTest
  # ...
end
```

or

```
class IntegrationHelperTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # ...
end

require 'test_helper'
require 'integration/integration_helper_test'
class PostIntegrationTest < IntegrationHelperTest
  # ..
end
```

Comment: Wow `module IntegrationHelper` worked! But why does `test_helper.rb` work when it's a `class ActiveSupport::TestCase`? Any helper method in there is magically available in the integration tests.

Comment: Not sure I get it. You can only include/extend modules and only inherit from classes.

Comment: It's automatically generated `test/test_helper.rb`. When you put a method in there, it is automatically available to all tests.

Answer (score 5):

**name_helper_test.rb** files are not for common code, these are for the testcases for your helpers.

According to [Rails Testing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) file that ends at **_test.rb** are for test cases, you should write tests in that file, because rake task detects from **_test.rb** that is file id for tests. So if you want to add some common code, **test_helper.rb** is there for you. You can even define your own files for helpers methods, for further guide about common test code read [A Guide for Writing Maintainable Rails Tests](http://www.littlelines.com/blog/2013/12/17/a-guide-for-writing-maintainable-rails-tests/).

Note: Questions in the comments of above answers is that you write your code in **test_helper.rb** outside of a class and due to use of [require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318144/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-require-in-ruby) all methods are available in other files, because they all require **test_helper.rb**.