# Rails: Moving a helper method form a test to test_helper.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

I am trying to move a helper method from a controller test to the test_helper.rb:

```
# example_controller_test.rb
require 'test_helper'
class ExampleControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  should 'get index' do
    turn_off_authorization
    get :show
    assert_response :success
  end
end

# test_helper.rb
class ActionController::TestCase
  def turn_off_authorization
    ApplicationController.any_instance
                         .expects(:authorize_action!)
                         .returns(true)
  end
end
```

However, I'm getting an error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `turn_off_authorization' for #<ExampleControllerTest:0x000000067d6080>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that I had to wrap the helper method into a module:

```
# test_helper.rb
class ActionController::TestCase
  module CheatWithAuth do
    def turn_off_authorization
      # some code goes here
    end
  end

  include CheatWithAuth
end
```

I still don't know why the original version didn't work.

The idea came from another answer:
[How do I write a helper for an integration test in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778032/how-do-i-write-a-helper-for-an-integration-test-in-rails)

**Edit**: Another solution just came from my friend:

```
# test_helper.rb
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def turn_off_authorization
    # some code goes here
  end
end
```

Note that `ActiveSupport::TestCase` (not `ActionController::TestCase`) is being used here.