# Why do I get the error uninitialized constant Stuff::HTTParty?

Tags: ruby, class, methods, rubygems, httparty

I have the HTTParty gem on my system and I can use it from within rails.

Now I want to use it standalone.

I am trying:

```
class Stuff
  include HTTParty
  def self.y
    HTTParty.get('http://www.google.com')
  end 
end
Stuff.y
```

but I get

```
$ ruby test_httparty.rb 
test_httparty.rb:2:in `<class:Stuff>': uninitialized constant Stuff::HTTParty (NameError)
        from test_httparty.rb:1:in `<main>'
07:46:52 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm/Dropnot/_/rails_apps/linker 73845718_get_method
$
```

Answer (score 26):

You have to `require 'httparty'`:

```
require 'httparty'

class Stuff
  include HTTParty
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Its all because of the include which exists with in the class

If you include a class with a module, that means you're "bringing in" the module's methods as instance methods.

If you need more clarity on include and require

I request you to refer to this wonderful SO Posting

[What is the difference between include and require in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14212020/1067466)

Here is an example which I have taken from the same posting

```
 module A
   def say
     puts "this is module A"
   end
 end

 class B
   include A
 end

 class C
   extend A
 end
B.say => undefined method 'say' for B:Class

B.new.say => this is module A

C.say => this is module A

C.new.say => undefined method 'say' for C:Class
```

Comment: @JörgWMittag I am sorry if it not meeting the requirement , I posted it because , the person posted the question wouldn't have asked this if he is aware of this issue .