# Why use both require and include in Rails class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, require

I thought I understood the difference between  `require` and `include` with the help of this  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318144/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-require-in-ruby) thread.

Then I stumbled on this piece of code from the [github page of the bcrypt-ruby gem.](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby) Why are they using both methods? So first single models are going to be loaded but then again through `include` all the functions?

```
require 'bcrypt'

 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # users.password_hash in the database is a :string
    include BCrypt
 .....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`require` loads a ruby file, making the BCrypt module available to your ruby code. It does not, necessarily have to be in the same file as the class you're including the module in.

`require` can also be used to make a ruby class defined in that file available (for instance, other classes you've defined in your project). As it's in a gem, bcrypt is on the ruby path, if it's a file in your project you may need to reference the full path, or use `require_relative`.

`include` takes the code in the bCrypt module and includes it to your User class, providing User with the methods and attributes declared in the BCrypt module.

Answer (score 3):

`require` loads the class.

`include` actually puts it inside the `User` class, e.g., including the module's methods as part of the definition of the `User` class.

The question you reference is pretty explicit about the difference.