# Ruby — after include, self.included is never invoked?

Tags: ruby, rspec, module, include

I'm writing an `acts_as_thingy` module, intended to be used as per

```
class TestThingy
  include ActsAsThingy

  acts_as_thingy :name
end
```

`ActsAsThingy` is defined as

```
module ActsAsThingy

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def acts_as_thingy *attributes
      attributes.each do |attribute|
        define_method attribute do
          "thingy - #{attribute.to_s}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And tested as

```
describe ActsAsReadOnlyI18nLocalised do
  let(:thingy) { TestThingy.new }

  it 'has a name method' do
    expect(thingy.name).to eq "thingy - name"
  end
end
```

What happens however is that, when I run the `rspec`, `ActsAsThingy`'s `self.included` method is never invoked, and `rspec` complains that there is no such method as `acts_as_thingy`.

I seem to be missing something entirely obvious, but just can't see it.

Why isn't the `self.included` method being called when I `include ActsAsThingy` in the class?

*update*

Stepping through with `pry` I can see that after the `include ActsAsThingy`, if I then look at `self.included_modules` it shows up as `[ActsAsThingy, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel]` So the `include` is working, it's not a paths issue or anything like that. The core question remains; why isn't `self.included` being invoked?

Comment: If I execute your within one script / file everthing works fine. Using `ruby 2.2.2p95`

Comment: Could there be a separate definition of ActsAsThingy somewhere?

Comment: turned out my class was missing a `require 'acts_as_thingy'` at the top.

Answer (score 2):

So after all that it turned out that I simply needed to add

`require 'acts_as_thingy'` to the top of the file that contained

```
class TestThingy
  include ActsAsThingy

  acts_as_thingy :name
end
```

I am not sure why Ruby didn't just throw an error when it couldn't find `ActsAsThingy` but it explains why the `self.included` method never got called (the include failed, but silently).

Answer (score -1):

Check your scope.
Check your file require path.
Include is used for including methods into other

> Modules

Require is what you want to use in your case.

Read up on the differences between require and include:
[What is the difference between include and require in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318144/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-require-in-ruby)

Here is my test code for your problem.

```
class A
  require_relative 'test.rb'


end

p('test')


module Test

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def p(str)
      print "#{str}"
    end
  end
end
```

output: 
`vagrant [test]> ruby file.rb
"test"`

Comment: My answer is correct in the fact that you needed to use require, yet it's downvoted and not accepted as the answer. T_T

Comment: Answered 4 days before original poster figured it out. Sigh.