# Why are Module classes in Rails 4 stored in lib folder vs. the app folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically, I have a method that I want to use upon multiple controllers.

```
def has_been_updated_today
  # Code that checks if a Model has been updated...
end
```

In [this blog](https://www.benfranklinlabs.com/where-to-put-rails-modules/) the author stated that it should be placed in the `/modules` directory, and then you can simply `include` in any file.

The problem I have with this is that everything related to my app is in the app directory. Everything about configuring intial set up is in the `config` just like everything about the database is in the `db`.

Furthermore, I am still get *re-familiar* with Rails, but how does `include filename` know where to get filename.rb from? How does it know it's in `lib` when I never stated it?

Comment: if you need a method that will be used in all your controllers you could place it in `ApplicationController`

Comment: "include filename" is not a thing. Did you mean `require` or misunderstood the article?

Comment: "how does include filename know where to get filename.rb from" - magic of rails auto-loading.

Comment: @Bohdan, the thing is.. it's only going to be used in a couple of my controllers. I realised I have another issue though... I need to be able to access the params... and I don't know if Modules can do that :(

Comment: @Sergio sorry, I meant, `include module_name`

Comment: `require`, not `include`.

Comment: It ended up working with `include module_name` , so I am not exactly sure.

Comment: There's a major difference between them and `include` is very rare in real-world ruby. http://stackoverflow.com/a/318170/336392

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you write that you want to use it in a few controllers and `concerns` seem the better solution for you problem.

```
# app/controllers/clock_controller.rb
class ClockUpdated
  include ClockConcern
  before_filter :has_been_updated_today, only: [:show] # just a example

  def update
    if !has_been_updated_today
      flash[:error] = 'Not been updated'
    end
  end
end

# app/controllers/concerns/clock_updated.rb
module ClockUpdated
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def has_been_updated_today
    return true
  end
end
```

Comment: As of right now, my code looks very similar to yours, besides the fact it's in `/lib`. I am going to research what `concerns` are for before... I make this change. Thank you for sharing this knowledge with me!

Comment: Did you mean `include ClockUpdated`?