# I want to use REXML in Fastfile, but when I include in Fastfile doesn't work

Tags: ruby, fastlane, rexml

Using Rexml in Fastfile, but fastlane can't recognize include, so I can't include Rexml module.

here is the error:

```
[!] Could not find action, lane or variable 'include'. Check out the documentation for more details: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions
```

here is my code in Fastfile

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rexml/document'
include REXML
```

Comment: Why do you use "include REXML" here? You may have misunderstand the "include" function on Ruby. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318144/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-require-in-ruby)

Comment: if not use include, how can I import this module in Fastfile?

Comment: Already imported with: require 'rexml/document'

Comment: you are right, but simple using this not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using:

```
require "rexml/document"
file = File.new( "movie.xml" )
xmldoc = REXML::Document.new file
```

instead of:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
require 'rexml/document' 

# include REXML
xmlfile = File.new("movie.xml")
xmldoc = rexml.Document.new(xmlfile)
```

solve my problem, but I still don't know why fastlane can't recognize include.