# how to test parslet atom right in irb

Tags: ruby, parslet

I found in parslet gem introduction something like this:

```
# Without structure: just strings.
  str('ooo').parse('ooo')                           # => "ooo"@0
  str('o').repeat.parse('ooo')                      # => "ooo"@0
```

source: [parslet gem](https://kschiess.github.io/parslet/get-started.html)

I did try this on irb (after require 'parslet') but it not working. Of course if I put this as a rule in a Parslet::Parser class it will work. My question is can we try parslet atom like above in irb? Is there any way to try that?

like this:

```
irb> require 'parslet'
irb> str('ooo').parse('ooo')
```

Comment: `include Parslet` would probably do.

Comment: Thanks Aleksei, i tried it seems work. This link help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318144/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-require-in-ruby