# Does Manifold preprocessor support splitting the code base

Tags: java, preprocessor-directive

Given that I use Manifold, a Java compiler plugin, and more specificaly the preprocessor, which acts very much like C/C++ directives, is it possible to split the code base based on these directives.

For example

```
#if VERSION_1
 old java code
#elif VERSION_2
 new java code
#else
  #error "Unsupported version"
#end if
```

I would like to generate the source code without the directives based on the version defined.
It is not clear to me if this is possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546659/how-to-provide-preprocessor-directives-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Preprocessor directives provided by manifold effectively mask away code in the body of a false #if/elif directive. Directives apply at the top level, as such you can use directives to turn on/off any and all code in a file. The [manifold-preprocessor](https://github.com/manifold-systems/manifold/tree/master/manifold-deps-parent/manifold-preprocessor) documentation explains this.

[image: manifold preprocessor]