# What's the name of a pre-compilation 'variable' constant in C?

Tags: java, c, constants

It's a long time since I did any coding of any sort.

I'm trying to remember the name (in C) of an item you put at the beginning of your code that allows compilation to a constant for efficiency but can have its value adjusted before compilation if necessary.

What is it called? (specifically the name in C and optionally the name in general)

Thanks.

Comment: You mean a macro? And if that's what you mean, those don't exist in Java.

Comment: you meant the preprocessor, like `#define` statements?

Comment: Ah - #define ! Thanks.

Comment: One question per question.

Comment: @Antti Haapala - Okay but my real question was "is *this thing* available in Java and/or JavaScript". I needed to know the name before I could ask. It seemed wasteful to ask lots of different questions but I see your point.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK because there are answers for **everything**. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927107/define-in-java . There are no answers to the question "can you help me", because [it is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @Antti Haapala - You win!

Comment: The term you are looking for is _integer constant expressions_. They can be placed behind a `#define` or elsewhere in the code. For example in `int x = 5 + 7;`, the `5 + 7` is an integer constant expression and will be calculated at compile-time. The resulting machine code will look something like "load 12 into register".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#define` statements allow you to define a constant at the beginning of your code.