# Global variables in Java

Tags: java

How do you define Global variables in Java  ?

Comment: Can you tell us *why* you want to define global variables in Java?

Comment: To access the variable from outside the class

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to include some sample code illustrating precisely what you want. It would help us recommend the best solution.

Comment: @Adam :I should be able to change the value of a variable in one class from another class.

Comment: You don't. There are no global variables in Java.

Comment: @aTJ I thought global variables should be accessible by all private (or more lightly restricted) methods, in the same class, i.e. member variables in java.

Answer (score 318, accepted):

To define Global Variable you can make use of static Keyword

```
public class Example {
    public static int a;
    public static int b;
}
```

now you can access a and b from anywhere
by calling

```
Example.a;

Example.b;
```

Comment: Be careful when doing this - when the Global class gets unloaded the variables will be undefined null. If you sell your app this will happen sooner or later and you keep looking for error everywhere but not there....

Comment: The `static` keyword makes variables globally accessible, while their class is loaded.

Comment: About class unloading: if there is any strong reference chain from any GC Root to an instance of Global or its children, or any compile-time reference from a loaded and not-unloadable class to Global, then the Class object relative to Global is strongly reachable, and, therefore, so is the ClassLoader that loaded Global; which makes it impossible to unload Global (since class unloading can only happen after the GC completely removes any strong reference to the ClassLoader that loaded a given class). If you have no references at all, how could the unloading be a problem???

Comment: @Abi I'd suggest your rename your class from `Global` to something else (`TestClass`?) in order not to give people the impression that there is such a thing as a `Global` Java keyword. Better safe than sorry :)

Comment: @user387184 To conclude, the values won't suddenly get null as long as there are references to that "global" class, right?

Comment: How those variables are going to work when modified and read from multiple threads, why not
...
public static volatile int a;

Answer (score 60):

You don't. That's by design. You shouldn't do it even if you could.

That being said you could create a set of public static members in a class named Globals.

```
public class Globals {
   public static int globalInt = 0;
   ///
}
```

but you really shouldn't :). Seriously .. don't do it.

Comment: as I have written above - when the class gets unloaded the variables loose their values to null and your app will crash.

Comment: Then what's the better approach that I can declare constants so that all class methods can access them?

Comment: Posts of this nature is the reason novices develop global variable phobia, and then we see all sorts of egregious techniques being devised to circumvent the global variable taboo, but achieve the same effect.

Comment: Down vote for saying, "don't do it." without explaining or referring to an explanation of why.

Comment: I'm going to do it.

Comment: How that variable is going to work when modified and read from multiple threads, why not ... public static volatile int globalInt;

Answer (score 50):

Another way is to create an interface like this:

```
public interface GlobalConstants
{
  String name = "Chilly Billy";
  String address = "10 Chicken head Lane";
}
```

Any class that needs to use them only has to implement the interface:

```
public class GlobalImpl implements GlobalConstants
{
  public GlobalImpl()
  {
     System.out.println(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering why this answer has (before mine) no up-votes.  
Does it not provide a reasonable alternative answer to that provided by all the other answers?

Comment: This is bad practice ->  GlobalImpl implements GlobalConstants

Comment: can you explain your point please? never been bad practise and please no need to vote down, thanks :)

Comment: Effective Java by Joshua Bloch, Chapter 4: Classes and Interfaces, Item 19: Use interfaces only to define types

"The constant interface pattern is a poor use of interfaces."

This book is worth reading! :)

Comment: And another comment from this book: "Constant interface antipattern - do not use!"

Comment: Additionally from JDK 1.5+ you can use static import for your global variables, implementing is not needed.

Comment: .... Right, that doesn't actually explain anything, that just says that some book said it was bad.

Comment: Here is a quote for you. Oracle says: "In order to get around this, people sometimes put static members into an interface and inherit from that interface. This is a bad idea. In fact, it's such a bad idea that there's a name for it: the Constant Interface Antipattern (see Effective Java Item 17). The problem is that a class's use of the static members of another class is a mere implementation detail. When a class implements an interface, it becomes part of the class's public API. Implementation details should not leak into public APIs."

Comment: The link where the above quote from oracle is: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/static-import.html

Comment: Well as dirty as this way to implement global variables may be, I like it! Thank you Evan, you safe me time and make my code look better.

Answer (score 25):

You are better off using dependency injection:

```
public class Globals {
    public int a;
    public int b;
}

public class UsesGlobals {
    private final Globals globals;
    public UsesGlobals(Globals globals) {
        this.globals = globals;
    }
}
```

Comment: True, though I think your use of "Globals" confuses things a bit :-).  Something like "Parameters" would be more fitting since it's not necessarily Global.

Answer (score 14):

Lots of good answers, but I want  to give this example as it's considered the more proper way to access variables of a class by another class: using getters and setters.

The reason why you use getters and setters this way instead of just making the variable public is as follows. Lets say your var is going to be a global parameter that you NEVER want someone to change during the execution of your program (in the case when you are developing code with a team), something like maybe the URL for a website. In theory this could change and may be used many times in your program, so you want to use a global var to be able to update it all at once. But you do not want someone else to go in and change this var (possibly without realizing how important it is). In that case you simply do not include a setter method, and only include the getter method.

```
public class Global{
    private static int var = 5;

    public static int getVar(){
        return Global.var;
    }

    //If you do not want to change the var ever then do not include this
    public static void setVar(int var){
        Global.var = var;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `public static class`?

Comment: That is not a valid java command. I dont believe it would even compile.

Comment: Do you mean the class declaration is invalid if we make `Global.java` file? I actually made your "Global" class as a sub class.

Answer (score 13):

Truly speaking there is not a concept of **"GLOBAL"** in a java OO program

Nevertheless there is some truth behind your question because there will be some cases where you want to run a method at any part of the program.
For example---random() method in Phrase-O-Matic app;it is a method should be callable from anywhere of a program.

So in order to satisfy the things like Above "We need to have Global-like variables and methods"

**TO DECLARE A VARIABLE AS GLOBAL.**

```
 1.Mark the variable as public static final While declaring.
```

**TO DECLARE A METHOD AS GLOBAL**.

```
 1. Mark the method as public static While declaring.
```

Because I declared global variables and method as static you can call them anywhere you wish by simply with the help of following code

ClassName.X

**NOTE**: X can be either method name or variable name as per the requirement and ClassName is the name of the class in which you declared them.

Answer (score 12):

There is no global variable in Java

Nevertheless, what we do have is a `static` keyword and that is all we need.
Nothing exists outside of class in Java. The `static` keyword represents a class variable that, contrary to instance variable, only has one copy and that transcends across all the instances of that class created, which means that its value can be changed and accessed across all instances at any point.

If you need a global variable which can be accessed beyond scopes, then this is the variable that you need, but its scope exists only where the class is, and that will be all.

Answer (score 11):

Nothing should be global, except for constants.

```
public class MyMainClass {
    public final static boolean DEBUGMODE=true;
}
```

Put this within your main class.  In other .java files, use it through:

```
if(MyMainClass.DEBUGMODE) System.out.println("Some debugging info");
```

Make sure when you move your code off the cutting room floor and into release you remove or comment out this functionality.

If you have a workhorse method, like a randomizer, I suggest creating a "Toolbox" package!  All coders should have one, then whenever you want to use it in a .java, just import it!

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as a truly global variable in Java.  Every static variable must belong to some class (like System.out), but when you have decided which class it will go in, you can refer to it from everywhere loaded by the same classloader.

Note that static variables should always be protected when updating to avoid race conditions.

Comment: java doesnt provide global variable functionally but if you want to have a global variable concept, we can make use of static keyword

Answer (score 4):

### Understanding the problem

I consider the qualification of *global variable* as a variable that could be accessed and changed anywhere in the code without caring about static/instance call or passing any reference from one class to another.

Usually if you have class A

```java
public class A {
    private int myVar;

    public A(int myVar) {
        this.myVar = myVar;
    }

    public int getMyVar() {
        return myVar;
    }

    public void setMyVar(int mewVar) {
        this.myVar = newVar;
    }
}
```

and want to access and update `myvar` in a class B,

```java
public class B{

    private A a;

    public void passA(A a){
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void changeMyVar(int newVar){
        a.setMyvar(newVar);
    }
}
```

you will need to have a reference of an instance of the class A and update the value in the class B like this:

```java
int initialValue = 2;
int newValue = 3;
A a = new A(initialValue);
B b = new B();
b.passA(a);
b.changeMyVar(newValue);
assertEquals(a.getMyVar(),newValue); // true
```

### Solution

So my solution to this, (even if i'm not sure if it's a good practice), is to use a singleton:

```java
public class Globals {
    private static Globals globalsInstance = new Globals();

    public static Globals getInstance() {
        return globalsInstance;
    }

    private int myVar = 2;

    private Globals() {
    }

    public int getMyVar() {
        return myVar;
    }

    public void setMyVar(int myVar) {
        this.myVar = myVar;
    }
}
```

Now you can get the Global unique instance anywhere with:

```java
Globals globals = Globals.getInstance();
// and read and write to myVar with the getter and setter like 
int myVar = globals.getMyVar();
global.setMyVar(3);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class GlobalClass {
     public static int x = 37;
     public static String s = "aaa";
}
```

This way you can access them with `GlobalClass.x` and `GlobalClass.s`

Answer (score 3):

If you need to update global property, a simple getter/setter wrapper class can be used as global variable. A typical example is shown below.

```java
public class GlobalHolder {

    private static final GlobalHolder INSTANCE = new GlobalHolder();

    private volatile int globalProperty;

    public static GlobalHolder getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public int getGlobalProperty() {
        return globalProperty;
    }

    public void setGlobalProperty(int globalProperty) {
        this.globalProperty = globalProperty;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GlobalHolder.getInstance().setGlobalProperty(10);
        System.out.println(GlobalHolder.getInstance().getGlobalProperty());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class GlobalImpl {   

 public static int global = 5;

}
```

you can call anywhere you want:

```
GlobalImpl.global // 5
```

Answer (score 2):

As you probably guess from the answer there is no global variables in Java and the only thing you can do is to create a class with static members:

```
public class Global {
    public static int a;
}
```

You can use it with `Global.a` elsewhere. However if you use Java 1.5 or better you can use the `import static` magic to make it look even more as a real global variable:

```
import static test.Global.*;

public class UseGlobal {
    public void foo() {
        int i = a;
    }
}
```

And *voilà*!

Now this is far from a best practice so as you can see in the commercials: *don't do this at home*

Answer (score 2):

Creating an independent file, eg. Example.java to use the 1st solution, is just fine. You can do that also within the app, if e.g. the global variables are special to your current app, etc.:

Create a class at the beginning and declare your variables in there:

```
class Globals {
  static int month_number;
  static String month_name;
}
```

You can then access these variables -- using them as 'Globals.month_number', etc. -- from averywhere in your app.

Comment: Instead of downvoting, can you please tell me  what is wrong with this solution? I am using it on a constant basis and it is the most convenient one. So I cannot do otherwise that considering this downvote as a personal thing or just done by a stupid person.

Answer (score 2):

very simple:

```
class UseOfGlobal
{
private static int a;
private static int b;
}
```

but it is always good to have local variables defined inside method blocks where ever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Generally Global variable (I assume you are comparing it with C,Cpp) define as `public static final`

like

```
class GlobalConstant{
    public static final String CODE  = "cd";
}
```

ENUMs are also useful in such scenario :

For Example  [`Calendar.JANUARY`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#JANUARY))

Comment: Does a global variable need to be final? Why?

Comment: "final" means "constant", so this is a global constant.

Comment: no , thats what Global variable means for if you want to share that variable and change the data also then just remove `final` but it certainly depends how you want to share , where you are using and all ,

Comment: What is the type of `CODE` in this example? Where is it defined?

Comment: Also note: CODE is in all caps, as its common java notation to use all caps for variables that you declare as final, and do not intend to change during the course of a program.

Answer (score 1):

There are no global variables in Java, but there are global classes with public fields. You can use static import feature of java 5 to make it look almost like global variables.

Answer (score 1):

To allow an unqualified access to static members of another class, you can also do a static import:

```
import static my.package.GlobalConstants;
```

Now, instead of `print(GlobalConstants.MY_PASSWORD);` 
you can use the Constant directly: `print(MY_PASSWORD);`

See [What does the "static" modifier after "import" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162187/what-does-the-static-modifier-after-import-mean) to decide about.

And consider the answer of Evan Lévesque about interfaces to carry the Constants.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the access of global while retaining priveleges.
// You can access variables in one class from another, with provisions.
// The primitive must be protected or no modifier (seen in example).

// the first class
public class farm{

  int eggs; // an integer to be set by constructor
  fox afox; // declaration of a fox object

  // the constructor inits
  farm(){
    eggs = 4;
    afox = new fox(); // an instance of a fox object

    // show count of eggs before the fox arrives
    System.out.println("Count of eggs before: " + eggs);

    // call class fox, afox method, pass myFarm as a reference
    afox.stealEgg(this);

    // show the farm class, myFarm, primitive value
    System.out.println("Count of eggs after : " + eggs);

  } // end constructor

  public static void main(String[] args){

    // instance of a farm class object
    farm myFarm = new farm();

  }; // end main

} // end class

// the second class
public class fox{

  // theFarm is the myFarm object instance
  // any public, protected, or "no modifier" variable is accessible
  void stealEgg(farm theFarm){ --theFarm.eggs; }

} // end class
```

Comment: What does this answer add that the other answers don't? I can't see any "new" value in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Java doesn't have any global variables. Other than local variables, all variables comes under the scope of any class defined in the program.
We can have static variables to have the scope of global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the concept, global variables, also known as instance variable are the class level variables,i.e., they are defined inside a class but outside methods. In order to make them available completely and use them directly provide the static keyword. 
So if i am writing a program for simple arithmetical operation and it requires a number pair then two instance variables are defined as such:

```
public class Add {
    static int a;
    static int b; 
    static int c;

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        c=sum();
        System.out.println("Sum is: "+c); 
    }

    static int sum() {
       a=20;
       b=30;
       return a+b;   
    }
}

Output: Sum is: 50
```

Moreover using static keyword prior to the instance variables enable us not to specify datatypes for same variables again and again. Just write the variable directly.

Comment: There are no global variables in Java; they are not also known as instance variables; defining them as `static` does not 'make them available completely'. First paragraph is nonsense. Example is poor practice.

Answer (score 0):

without `static` this is possible too:

```
class Main {
  String globalVar = "Global Value";

  class Class1 {
    Class1() {
      System.out.println("Class1: "+globalVar);
      globalVar += " - changed";
  } }
  class Class2 {
    Class2() {
      System.out.println("Class2: "+globalVar);
  } }

  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Main m = new Main();
    m.mainCode();
  }
  void mainCode() {
    Class1 o1 = new Class1();
    Class2 o2 = new Class2();
  }
}

/*
Output:
Class1: Global Value
Class2: Global Value - changed
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

**Object-Oriented Programming** is built with the understanding that the scope of variables is closely exclusive to the class object that encapsulates those variables.

The problem with creating "global variables" is that it's not industry standard for Java. It's not industry standard because it allows multiple classes to manipulate data asyncronized, if you're running a multi-threaded application, this gets a little more complicated and dangerous in terms of thread-safety. There are [various other reasons](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad) why using global variables are ineffective, but if you want to avoid that, I suggest you resort to **[Aspect-Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)**.

**Aspect-Oriented Programming** negates this problem by putting the parent class in charge of the scope through something called "advices", which adds additional behavior to the code without actually modifying it. It offers solutions to cross-cutting concerns, or global variable usage.

[Spring](https://spring.io/) is a Java framework that utilizes AOP, and while it is traditionally used for web-applications, the core application can be used universally throughout the Java framework (8.0 included). This might be a direction you want to explore more.

Answer (score -1):

To define Global Variable you can make use of static Keyword

```
public final class Tools {
  public static int a;
  public static int b;
}
```

now you can access a and b from anywhere by calling

```
Tools.a;
Tools.b;
```

Yoy are right...specially in J2ME...
  You can avoid NullPointerException by putting inside your MidLet constructor
(proggy initialization) this line of code:

```
new Tools();
```

This ensures that Tools will be allocated before any instruction
that uses it.

That's it!

Comment: Um... Sorry, but what does this add that isn't already covered by the existing answers?

Comment: Maybe you are right..but this answer explain things like memory allocation.

Comment: There are not static top-level classes in java