# I need to make a variable accessible to the whole program in Java

Tags: java, global-variables

So my problem is this. I have a class called `Globals` that contains all the variables I need all over the program. It works fine for things like strings, integers and other things that you can use the `=` operation on. For example:

```
public class Globals {
   public static int globalInteger = 23;
   public static String globalString = "Hello, dude.";
   public static UserProfile globalUserProfile;
}
```

Somewhere in the project, I access them using these:

`Globals.globalInteger += 17;`

`Globals.globalString = "Why, hello there!";`

However, I am trying to make a class that I wrote myself global (`UserProfiles.class`). This class does not use the `=` operation, hence, it is always `null` when I access it from somewhere else and I get `java.lang.nullPointerException`. For example if I do this (`newProfile(String)` is a method inside `UserProfiles.class`):

`Globals.globalUserProfile.newProfile(profileName);`

I get `java.lang.NullPointerException`. How can I make my `UserProfile.class` variable accessible all throughout the project? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for the record, the pattern of "Globals" (especially the `+= 17` *shudder*) is not a good one.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646577/global-variables-in-java

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm pretty new to Java and I'm still getting confused on some of the basics. I'll read on that. Thanks.

Comment: If you edit your question to explain _why_ you want to do this and give some real examples of some of the values that you think you need to store globally, folks can comment on better ways to accomplish your goals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Singleton design pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

[Examples of GoF Design Patterns in Java's core libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns)

Answer (score 5):

Write a so called factory class which builds your whole project in one step.

Example:

```
// a class which store configuration parameters - must be instanstiable!
public class Configuration {
   public Configuration() {
       // get configuration from Properties file, Resource Bundle etc.
   } 
}

public class A {
    private Configuration configuration;

    public A(Configuration configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
}

public class B {
    private Configuration configuration;
    private A a;

    public B(A a, Configuration configuration) {
        this.a = a;
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
}

public class C {
    private Configuration configuration;
    private B b;

    public C(B b, Configuration configuration) {
        this.b = b;
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
}
```

Here you have 3 classes and one configuration class. All of them are dependent on the configuration class, C is dependent on B and B is dependent on A.

As you can see, the dependencies are reflected by the constructor parameters, which is good because dependencies are explicit (that means, you now which dependencies are needed without having too look at the source code).

But, how do you build this object graph? Well, by using a factory class (here, it's even a static factory):

```
public class ApplicationFactory {
    // prevents instantiation
    private ApplicationFactory() {};

    public static C buildApplicationGraph() {
        // first, build the leaf objects (objects without other dependencies), here
        // Configuration
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        // now, start injecting the dependencies needed
        // a only need a Configuration object
        A a = new A(configuration);

        // B needs a Configuration and an A object
        B b = new B(a, configuration);

        // we're done here        
        return new C(b, configuration);         
    }
}
```

As you can see, you are building the object graph bottom up. All dependencies are explicit, and you are seperating the construction process from the business logic.

What we have done here is constructor dependency injection, i.e. we passed in the dependencies every class needs via the constructor. And for creating the objects needed, we wrote a factory.

In the end, we have lightweight classes (no construction work here), explicit dependencies (which you don't have using a Singleton), and maximum flexibility (the factory could even return a subclass of C).

**EDIT**

One further advantage is that you're able to test you classes in isolation, as you could easily mock the parameters (e.g. by passing in subclasses of the parameters).

Answer (score 2):

You can instantiate your class by default in your Globals class :

```
public static UserProfile globalUserProfile = new UserProfile();
```

or you have to declare a factory method inside of UserProfile class.

Comment: I would suggest a get method as well, to check whether or not globalUserProfile is null and instantiate it if it is instead of having a public accessible variable. `getUserProfile() { return globalUserProfile != null ? globalUserProfile : (globalUserProfile = new UserProfile()); }`