# How to create a list of global variables that can be accessible from different classes?

Tags: java, global-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Global variables in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646577/global-variables-in-java)

How to create a list of global variables that can be accessible from different classes? Should I create a class of global variables...?

Comment: Use storage and access modifiers.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve. People might be able to provide a better answer or perhaps tell you why it's not a good idea.

Comment: Generally global state is considered a really, really bad idea. Goto is completely harmless in comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create one class called ConstantCodes.java

Now declare your variable in this class has follows,

```
public class ConstantCodes
{
      public static String PublicVariable = "I am public variable"; 
}
```

Now you can above variable anywhere from your project using below line,

```
String myStr = ConstantCodes.PublicVariable;
```

Comment: If I don´t know apriori the values of global variables and want to define them from JTextField (SWING), then can I do something like this: ConstantCodes.PublicVariable = Integer.parse(txtBox.getText().toString()); ?

Comment: yes, you can but in the starting of the class. just store the values in db & try to retrieve from it, if no value found then display default one. got it ?

Answer (score 2):

you can say

```
    public  class GlobalVariables{
    public static final Integer INT_VAR=12;
    public static final String STR_VAR="abcd";
//  public static final List<SomeObject> someObjectList=new ArrayList<SomeObject>()// this can be populated using some method later.
    }
```

you can also use `interface`s and `enum`s for declaring global variables..

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would create a class containing public static variables and then use `import static MyClass.*` in each class the variables are required.

```
import static MyClass.*;

class MainClass {
    void someMethod() {
        // using "import static" there's no need to do
        // int x = MyClass.SomeStaticInt;
        int x = SomeStaticInt;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Should I create a class of global variables...?

Yes. create a static class having `public static final` fields.

`final` will mark those fields as constants.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `interface` or `enum` for constants declaration.