# What design pattern should be used for a global configuration

Tags: java, design-patterns, configuration, global-variables

I've been reading that using static variables in a class that's never instantiated is a bad idea, because the variables may turn null when the class is not longer in memory. Makes sense.

This is what I've been doing for an example

```
public class MasterParameters {

public static boolean           DEBUG_MODE =                true;
protected MasterParameters(){
    // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
}
```

}

I've also heard using a Singleton is equally bad and people suggest using "dependency injection" -- This seems complicated and overkill for what I need, however. Am I just not looking at the right examples?

I want an easy way to define a variable in **one spot** that can be accessed from anywhere in my code without having to pass a parameters object around. What do you suggest?
Thanks :)

Comment: "I want an easy way to define a variable in one spot that can be accessed from anywhere in my code without having to pass a parameters object around. What do you suggest?" If this is what you want, it's a Singleton,  or a global variable or whatever name you prefer for it.

Comment: Your first paragraph actually does _not_ make sense.  You misinterpreted what you were reading, or your reference is very bad.  Stuff does not "just disappear" from memory in Java.

Comment: Your example is actually one form of the singleton pattern.

Comment: This is good to know, do you have a source? I read on stack overflow saying that the class will eventually be unloaded and the variables will be null which scared me and made me post this in the first place. I guess you can't believe everything. Had a few upvotes which lended to the credibility, though.

Comment: Look at the post here and the second comment with 14 up votes saying NOT to use the design pattern I posted above. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646577/global-variables-in-java

Comment: You should give the reference to the "disappearing values" so I can downvote it; it is complete junk.

Comment: Just did :) Maybe I misinterpreted it? The relevant text is "That being said you could create a set of public static members in a class named Globals. but you really shouldn't :). Seriously .. don't do it." and someone backs it up saying you will lose the variables.

Comment: The post with the 14 upvotes says you should not use _global variables_.  The singleton pattern is a way to define a global variable.  You are involuntarily trolling here: there is a lot of debate about using or not using global variables.  I am on the side that you should not use them.  If some object needs some value, it should be passed as a parameter, not obtained from a global variable.  Code with global variables becomes unreadable and unmaintainable unless it's quite shorth.

Comment: I understand that since your variable is just some debugging flag and that you don't want to pass it everywhere to every method.  You should probably just try to use a debugger and also test your program bits by bits as you progress so that you don't need to build some debugging infrastructure within your code.

Comment: Just to clarify: I upvoted the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646577/global-variables-in-java#4646605) in the other post saying that you should not use global variables.  It's the second comment to that answer that makes no sense (losing static values).

Comment: Didn't mean to troll; I just wanted to make sure it was OK to use Global Variables from a reliability point of view. I don't care so much about semantics and I understand the pros and cons to using them and not, as long as the cons doesn't include "it will turn null eventually". Much appreciated and thanks for all your comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest Singleton pattern (I know many people don't like it), but it seems the simplest solution that will work. Take a look at this piece of code:

```
public enum Constants {
    INSTANCE;

    public void isInDebugMode() { 
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is how you use it (even from static code):

```
if(Constants.INSTANCE.isInDebugMode()) {....}
```

You might also think about some more sophisticated solution:

```
public enum Constants {
    DEBUG(true),
    PRINT_VARS(false);

    private boolean enabled;

    private Constants(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
if(Constants.DEBUG.isEnabled()) {....}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to use a static method, instead of a variable:

```
public class MasterParameters {

public static boolean DebugMode(){
     return true; // change this
}
protected MasterParameters(){
    // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
}
```