# How to make a variable global in java

Tags: java, client-server, global-variables, multiplayer, static-variables

In multi player online games. how to keep a variable global? we are developing an online game and we need a global variable.There will be one server and multiple clients.how can we keep a common variable which is static and editable by all the clients in syncronisation. can we have some suggestions?

Comment: Did you hear about public static?

Comment: @aaronps Have you read all question ?

Comment: Seems I didn't read the whole question.

Comment: @Vash thanks, now I read all the question and now have an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global variables in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646577/global-variables-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

If you ever move to a cluster, having a heap-based variable will become a problem since it will not be global enough (each node will have a separate copy).

If this is not an issue, and if by "variable" you mean a simple thing like a String or Long, then the best option is to use the `java.util.concurrent.Atomic*` classes. For example,

```
public static final AtomicLong id = new AtomicLong();
```

The most important advantage of this is that it can be atomically updated using compare-and-swap and get-and-set, for example `id.getAndIncrement();`

Answer (score 0):

The *Server* must control the variable.

When the clients wants to make a modification to that variable, they don't change it, they must send a message to the server telling the new wanted value. The server stores it and broadcast a message to all the clients, then they all update that variable with the new value.

Of course, if the server modifies by itself, it just broadcasts the new value.

Answer (score 0):

**-** `public static final` is used to make a variable Global in Java.

**-** But then `volatile` must be used for this, so that the **operation occurs directly to the memory and read from memory directly.**

**-** It would be better to use classes from  `java.util.concurrent.Atomic` .

**-** You can use `AtomicInteger`, `AtomicLong`, `AtomicReference` etc....