# Eclipse - Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete CompilationUnit

Tags: java, eclipse

I have only one line that's declaring a variable.
Yet it's giving me problems,
so far, I have tried:

- remaking the project, making sure it is an Android Application Project
- deleting everything but that line, that's why there's only one line
- referring to the package (really out of ideas)

Yet, I'm getting:

```
    Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete CompilationUnit
```

With two variables declared I get on the previously declared variables:

```
    Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
```

[image: To me, this doesn't make any sense]

Comment: What makes you think you can put that line there?

Comment: You should have this inside a `class`.

Comment: Thanks for extrapolating Maroun, even though I feel stupid now. Heh, too many days without java for me I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java there is no concept of global variables. All the code should go either in a class, interface or enum.

Comment: What do I do then if I do not intend to use that class?
How do I declare variables I intend to use globally?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646577/global-variables-in-java
-------- That's new...