# Is there a way to update an object from the main class to all the other classes within the program?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, java.util.scanner

Is there a way to user the Scanner class in ex. Test_Main.java and make lets say int number1 = scan.nextInt() and then have number1 be one be visible to all the classes and have it change in all of the other classes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global variables in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646577/global-variables-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "static" keyword to make the changes available in all other classes. Below is the sample.

```
public static int number1 = 1;
```

static makes the variable class level, so you have to use it using the class name. In your case you can use as follows:

```
Test_Main.number1
```