# Whati Is Global And Instance Variable

Tags: java

Please tell me the difference between a global variable and an instance variable. I am a little bit confused about it. Also, what is a user-defined variable?

Comment: [FYI](http://java-latte.blogspot.in/2014/01/global-variable-vs-class-variable-vs.html)

Comment: The closest thing to a 'global variable' in Java is implemented with a public constant in some (public) class or interface, as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646577/global-variables-in-java. An instance variable is a field at the class level.

Answer (score 0):

> Instance variables are non static variables declared in a class, but outside a method, constructor or any block.
>
> Class(similar to global, as there is no term as global in java) variables also known as static variables are declared with the static keyword in a class, but outside a method, constructor or a block.