# How to change attribute value globally in Java?

Tags: java, scope, global, globalization, assign

I am asking the user to input a value and then I am assigning the same to an attribute but, I want that change to be global. I searched on internet but yet I am not able to find the working solution for it. By the way I m using Java.

Thanx in advance.....

---

Comment: You should be less vague. What is that attribute? Where is it defined? How is that class used and how instantiated? Do you know what `static` means? (if no, then search for it)

Comment: And btw, note that `static` fields have disadvantages, too. One of the big ones is that they make testing harder, since it's easy for a test to change a value from what other tests expect.

Comment: let the attribute be of any data type, int , double and so. Yes I do know about static. I need to take an input by a function and without using return i want to use that value outside its scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been extensively covered. If you are looking on how to make a variable global/accessible from outside a class, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646577/global-variables-in-java).

However, if you are looking to make a global variable that can be accessed in and ONLY in a class, you can use the `private static` Keyword. Here is an example:

```
class myClass {

    private static int myGlobalVariable;     //Can only be accessed from methods in myClass

    void changeMyVariable (int value) {
        // Data validation here if needed
        this.myGlobalVariable = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok so the keyword "this" will be used!!!!!!!
thanks oscar... I m new to Programming and to learn via coding...

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad I helped you. As you are learing (like me) feel free to post your WORKING code on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com/) website for full peer review. As another member told me, just keep in mind that Code Review is a place where **working** code is reviewed and not a place to ask _how to make it work_, but rather _how to make it work_ **better**.

Answer (score 1):

Java has [class members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for that. Also known as `static` fields.