# How do I use variables from different method in java?

Tags: java, object, methods

First off let me say that I am very new to java so this is really simple but I have this date object and I made an actionlistener method but it won't let me use the object in there. How do I make it so that I can access in the method?

```
            jp = new JPanel();
        jta = new JTextArea(100, 100);
        jta.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(460,420));
        jta.setLineWrap(true);
        jta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        Date date = new Date();
        jb = new JButton("Tommorow");
        jl = new JLabel();
        jf = new JFrame();

        jf.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        jl.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
        add(jl, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        add(jp);
        jp.add(jb, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(jta);

        jb.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       jta.setText("");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        date = cal.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Which object are you trying to access?

Comment: Just make `date` a [private field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html).

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Check the link...

Comment: but how do I make an object private

Comment: Again, check the link -- it's explained pretty well under Access Modifiers, along with an example to boot.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently having a problem with the scope of your variables.  You cannot use variables from your another method in the method `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`.  Above you used:

```
jta = new JTextArea(100, 100);
jta.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(460,420));
jta.setLineWrap(true);
jta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

The variable `jta` is local to that method and cannot be accessed by other methods.  The same goes for `Date date = new Date();`.  If you want to continue to use these variables down below create an object contains these variables.  It could look something like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    private JTextArea textArea;
    private Date date;

    public MyClass(JTextArea textArea, Date date) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public JTextArea getTextArea() {
        return this.textArea;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're having a scope problem. You can't access variables from other functions unless they are first declared as globals, or passed around in function parameters

Comment: so how do I fix it? Sorry I'm new to java as I said.

Comment: Java doesn't have global variables, or functions.

Comment: @RadinHakimjavadi where is actionPerformed getting called?

Comment: @JoeyWood The class doesn't invoke it directly. Rather a superclass of `JButton`, `AbstractButton`, fires the event (and calls the method) when the button is pushed.

Comment: Not really sure what I'm looking at above the actionPerformed method but if you set date in a `public static Date date = new Date()` when you're defining the class, you can access that anywhere by className.date

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646577/global-variables-in-java