# Assigning a file name to a variable in java

Tags: java, variables, file-handling

I want to simply assign the file name "database.txt" to a string type variable say "fname".
What is the code for it for java.
I want to use relative file destinations.

Comment: `String fname = "database.txt"` ?

Comment: Have you Googled at least once?

Comment: omg stop -1ing just because the question is basic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global variables in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646577/global-variables-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this :

File file = new File("your/path");
String str = file.getName();