# How can I get my inputstream result of a http request outside the string buffer input loop

Tags: java, api, javafx

I'm using openstreetmap
I can only see the inputstream inside the while loop

Here's my code inside the initialize of the javafx Controller:

```
try {
    URL myurl;
    myurl = new URL("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=The+White+House,+Washington+DC&amp;format=json&amp;addressdetails=1");
    URLConnection yc = myurl.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                response.append(inputLine);

} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(WeatherUpdateController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

I am trying to get the StringBuffer inside a string variable so I can search it.

Comment: `final String asString = response.toString();`

Comment: @user2478398 the final string only contains a value inside the while loop and i can't get it outside of it

Comment: Make the `StringBuffer` global and try `StringBuilder`.

Comment: That can't be correct.  `StringBuffer` won't clear itself just because an implied scope ends, and `String`s are immutable and won't _ever_ clear themselves.  Are you sure you've not just declared your `String` in the _scope_ of the `while` block and just can't access it from outside?  If that's the case, just close the while block and _then_ to `response.toString()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646577/global-variables-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `StringBuffer#toString()` like so:

```
String str = response.toString();
```

Please note that you can  use `StringBuilder` instead if you don't need synchronization. [Source here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/difference-between-stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer)

Comment: It's the same thing, the str variable is unrecognizable outside the while loop 
if i append it to anything inside the while(true) loop i can't get it ouside the loop

Comment: You should put it after the loop.