# Android Studio: Start and Stop audio using mediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, xml, android-mediaplayer

How to `start` and `stop` playing the music using the same button. The code below will play the song multiple times (overlaping) if I click it repeatedly.

And another problem is where to insert `starTimer` and `StopTimer` function so the starTimer will active is the sound is not playing and stopTimer will active if the sound is playing.

Updated Code:

```
   public void playFile(View v) {
    if (mediaPlayer == null)
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    try {

        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(question.getAudio());

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(@NotNull MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        stopSelf();
    }

    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        //pause music
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    } else {
        //play music
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Xml file:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/audQuestion"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Play"
    android:onClick="playFile"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

and for the startTimer stopTimer function

```
public void starTimer() {
    timer = new Timer(Constant.TIME_PER_QUESTION, Constant.COUNT_DOWN_TIMER);
    timer.start();
}

public void stopTimer() {
    if (timer != null)
        timer.cancel();
}
```

Comment: Have you get the solution?

Comment: Not yet Ali..Do you have some solution?

Comment: I add my answer if you have any issue then please ping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please define below code at Global:

```
private Button play_pause;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
```

Now in `onCreate` Method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        play_pause = findViewById(R.id.play_pause);
    }
```

Play pause button:

```
play_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            mediaPlayer.pause();
                        } else {
                            mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }
                    } 
                }
            });
```

When Audio is ready to play:

```
private void readyToPlay(Uri uri) {
        try {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(activity, uri);//Write your location here
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Audio is complete then auto stop:

```
@Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }
    }
```

Don't forgot to add this line:

```
implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener
```

Answer (score 0):

better you make one boolean values on button click then handling easily

isClick is false means if will execute other going else.else spot you make mediaplayer stop and timer stop function

```
boolean isClick=false;
public void playFile(View v){
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); if(!isClick){

    isClick=true;
        try {

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(question.getAudio());

            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                     if( mediaPlayer.isPlaying() ) {
                     mediaPlayer.stop();}  mp.start();
                     starTimer();
                 }
             });
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            stopSelf();
        }

    }else{ 
        if( mediaPlayer.isPlaying() ) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            stopTimer();
        }
     isClick=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The audio still doesnt stop if i click the same button. Its still playing (overlapping) itself.

Comment: now you check the code in else spot stop media and  timer..and when you going to play mediaplayer before that you have to check mediaplayer is playing or not .playing means stop and start

Answer (score 0):

To stop the music/sound using media player create a boolean value `isPlaying`. make it true when the music is playing

declare isPlaying as [global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4646577/7948109) like

```
private boolean isPlaying = false;
```

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
    isPlaying = true;
}
```

now you can create a method which will check the value of `isPlaying` and play or pause the music, call this method `onClick()` of button

```
private playPauseMusic(){
    if (!isPlaying) {
        //play music
        isPlaying = true;
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } else {
        //pause music
        isPlaying = false;
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}
```

hope this will help!

Comment: I have update the code above. I am really sorry i am newbie to java language. I am getting red warning on "@NotNull" and :isPlaying" code.

Comment: I updated the answer, please check. please make your `MediaPlayer` global too

Answer (score 0):

> The code below will play the song multipletimes (overlaying) if i
>   click it repeatedly.

Because your are instantiating the media player object each time you hit the button, to solve this, make your medica player object a class field, not a method local field & check first if the object is not null before instantiating it

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public void playFile(View v) { 
    if (mediaPlayer == null)
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    // The reset of the code
    ...
```

And no need to have a variable to check if the media is playing as you can check that directly from mediaplayer object

```
if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
} else if () {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

So change your code to

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public void playFile(View v) {
    if (mediaPlayer == null)
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    try {

        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(question.getAudio());

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(@NotNull MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        stopSelf();
    }

    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        //pause music
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    } else if () {
        //play music
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

For timer issue, it's not that clear, how do you implement your timer?

Comment: else if () { mediaPlayer.start(); }  doesnt work. I need to remove "if" statement so it can pass building apk. The result is when the button click for second time, it destroy the activity and i got warning "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick". If i remove the "if (mediaPlayer == null)" statement, i got no error but the issue (overlapping multiple audio) is occured again.