# What is the purpose of using static to import package?

Tags: java, java-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the “static” modifier after “import” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162187/what-does-the-static-modifier-after-import-mean)

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.APPEND;
```

What is the role of static in it?And why is it mandatory?

Answer (score 3):

This oracle documentation should help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html

Answer (score 0):

Because in your code you can use:

```
APPEND
```

If you didn't imported this as static you had to give full path:

```
java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.APPEND;
```

Answer (score 0):

Copied from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_import).

> Static import is a feature introduced in the Java programming language
>   that allows members (fields and methods) defined in a class as public
>   static to be used in Java code without specifying the class in which
>   the field is defined. This feature was introduced into the language in
>   version 5.0.