# Are there any advantages of using static import over import?

Tags: java, import, static-import

Consider the following class

```
public final class Constant {
  public static final String USER_NAME="user1";
  //more constant here
}
```

This class in the package B.

Now I am going to use this in package A. Consider following two ways which can use.

Method 1- use `import B.Constant`

```
import B.Constant;

public class ValidateUser {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   if(Constant.USER_NAME.equals("user1")){

   }
  }
 }
```

Method 2- use `import static B.Constant.USER_NAME;`

```
import static B.Constant.USER_NAME;

public class ValidateUser {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   if(USER_NAME.equals("user1")){

   }
 }
}
```

My question is is there any difference or advantage normal import over static import in this case?

Comment: Hi this post may answer ur question i believe..                               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162187/what-does-the-static-modifier-after-import-mean

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The only difference between a normal `import` and an `import static` is that the latter is for moving `static` members of some other class or interface — *especially* constants — into scope. It's up to you whether you use it; I like it because it keeps the body of the class shorter, but YMMV.

There are no performance benefits or penalties to using them (except possibly when compiling, as if you care about that) as they compile into identical bytecode.

Comment: By the way, I don't recommend static importing non-constant static fields. I suspect doing so will be very confusing.

Comment: I'd go further than that. I would recommend against *declaring* non-final static fields in the first place

Answer (score 20):

The main difference is **Readablity**, `Constant.USER_NAME` is less readable when compared to `USER_NAME`.

From [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html):

> Used appropriately, static import can make your program more readable, by removing the boilerplate of repetition of class names.

But in any case, try to avoid doing

`import static B.Constant.*;`

because it can pollute its namespace with all the static members you import.

Comment: i think `Constant.USER_NAME` is more readable, when i would read only `USER_NAME` in `ValidateUser`, i would immediately think someone has declared this constant twice by mistake

Comment: Can you please elaborate why import static B.Constant.*; is a bad idea? What if I had an interface of 200 constants and actually use about 50 of them in a class - should I import those 50 only or can I static import the whole interface.* ? Because 50 import statements at the top might make the class messy.

Answer (score 13):

I use static imports very rarely and only where they actually make the code a little easier to follow.

According to oracle:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html

> So when should you use static import? Very sparingly! Only use it when
>   you'd otherwise be tempted to declare local copies of constants, or to
>   abuse inheritance (the Constant Interface Antipattern). In other
>   words, use it when you require frequent access to static members from
>   one or two classes. If you overuse the static import feature, it can
>   make your program unreadable and unmaintainable, polluting its
>   namespace with all the static members you import. Readers of your code
>   (including you, a few months after you wrote it) will not know which
>   class a static member comes from. Importing all of the static members
>   from a class can be particularly harmful to readability; if you need
>   only one or two members, import them individually. Used appropriately,
>   static import can make your program more readable, by removing the
>   boilerplate of repetition of class names.

The important points to note here:

- Use it when you require frequent access to static members from one or two classes
- Used appropriately, static import can make your program more readable

And commenter @Donal Fellows, says appropriately that using an IDE to manage static imports is less risky. I agree as modern IDE's have come a long way and will take out a lot of the pains of managing dependancies and tracing method calls back to a parent.

Comment: Note that you really want to use your IDE to manage your code, and that makes using static imports much less risky; the IDE knows where the constant came from…

Comment: @Husman "Readers of your code (including you, a few months after you wrote it) will not know which class a static member comes from." - this is not so true, for example if you use good IDE (Eclipse, Idea, Netbeans, ...) with just one key press you know where it come from ;-)

Comment: @LadislavDANKO, yes that has been mentioned. But (a) the text was quoted from Oracle, not made up by me. (b) the use of IDE is already mentioned by another commenter. (c) Not everyone always has access to a full blown IDE on their choice of platform - there are small PC's (rPi or other pocket PCs) or non windows OS which cannot run certain IDEs or vim over ssh for example

Comment: Need to be used only when one or 2 members are needed. if you need only one or two members, import them individually.

Answer (score 4):

For example all methods in Math class are static an we call all of them as Math.mathod().But if we import math class like this : `import static java.lang.Math.*;` We don't have to add Math before the method :

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println(sqrt(25));
        System.out.println(log(100));
        System.out.println(PI);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Static imports** let you avoid qualifying static members with class names.

Once the static member is imported then you can use it in your code without the class name prefix.

Good example:

```
import static sample.SampleStaticValues.NUM_ZERO;
…

enum OddEven {odd,even}


//need not do SampleConstants.NUM_ZERO due to static import feature
if(num % 2 == NUM_ZERO){
   System.out.println("The num " + num + " is: " + OddEven.even);
}

  package sample;
  public class SampleStaticValues {
  public static int NUM_ZERO = 0;
  public static int NUM_ONE = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Static imports** are used to save your time and typing. If you hate to type same thing again and again then you may find such imports interesting.

The **import** allows the java programmer to access classes of a package without package qualification.

The s**tatic import** feature allows to access the static members of a class without the class qualification.

Lets understand this with the help of below examples:

Example 1: Without Static Imports

```
class Demo1{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      double var1= Math.sqrt(5.0);
      double var2= Math.tan(30);
      System.out.println("Square of 5 is:"+ var1);
      System.out.println("Tan of 30 is:"+ var2);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Square of 5 is:2.23606797749979
Tan of 30 is:-6.405331196646276
```

Example 2: Using Static Imports

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.lang.Math.*;
class Demo2{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      //instead of Math.sqrt need to use only sqrt
      double var1= sqrt(5.0);
      //instead of Math.tan need to use only tan
      double var2= tan(30);
      //need not to use System in both the below statements
      out.println("Square of 5 is:"+var1);
      out.println("Tan of 30 is:"+var2);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Square of 5 is:2.23606797749979
Tan of 30 is:-6.405331196646276
```

Answer (score 1):

**Guys today we came across a big disadvantage of static imports. Just sharing it below.**

1. XXXConsts.java had EVENT_ID (EVENT_ID = "EVENT_ID")  which was statically imported in a class XXXComceteImpl.java that extends from AbstractService.java
2. XXXZeloImpl.java that extends from AbstractService.java wanted EVENT_ID = "eventId". So EVENT_ID = "eventId" was declared in AbstractService.java.
3. Now #1 was broken as the EVENT_ID  in  XXXComceteImpl.java was referring to EVENT_ID in AbstractService.java
4. May be the naming of EVENT_ID = "eventId" should have been different.
5. **Note** :- Names of the classes are redacted version so it looks unusual.

Comment: May I know why this was given -1?  I faced this in a legacy code and had to refactor it. I thought I can share what I came across. I don't see anything wrong in highlighting what I faced

Answer (score 0):

In order to access static members, it is necessary to qualify references with the class they came from. For example, one must say:

```
double r = Math.cos(Math.PI * theta);
or
System.out.println("Blah blah blah");
```

You may want to avoid unnecessary use of static class members like Math. and System. For this use static import. For example above code when changed using static import is changed to:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.lang.Math.PI;
import static java.lang.Math.cos;
...
double r = cos(PI * theta);
out.println("Blah blah blah");
...
```

So whats the advantage of using above technique? Only advantage that I see is readability of the code. Instead of writing name of static class, one can directly write the method or member variable name.
Also keep one thing in mind here. Ambiguous static import is not allowed. i.e. if you have imported java.lang.Math.PI and you want to import mypackage.Someclass.PI, the compiler will throw an error. Thus you can import only one member PI.