# How to declare global lists in Eclipse RCP

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have some data stored in 5 lists. I need to acces these lists through all rcp project. The problem is that I can't refer to a static variable in the content provider where these lists are created.

I don't know also how to make variables global without calling them like ClassName.VariableName .

Can you help me with a solution for these problems ?

Thank you !

P.S. For admins, please read the questions before marking them as duplicate, I have searched the topic on stackoverflow and none of the questions already here can help me solve this

Comment: Everything in Java has to be in a class, so you must use 'ClassName.xxx'. Why is this a problem?

Comment: It's a problem because I have to write this every time, also for the lists this isn't working

Comment: Read about [import static](http://stackoverflow.com/q/162187/2670892)

Comment: I tried to import the class and it still doesn't work, the variables from the imported class aren't recognized without ClassName in front of the variable....