# How do I use the Titan API?

Tags: java, groovy, titan

I would like to configure Titan Db using the API. I have created a Groovy script like so...

```
import static com.thinkaurelius.titan.core
```

Then on the command line...

```
bin/groovy -cp  "/Users/Ian/titan/lib/:titan-core-0.5.0.jar"   "../webstormprojects/project1/titan.groovy"
```

Then...

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: /Users/Ian/WebstormProjects/project1/titan.groovy:
>   1: unable to resolve class com.thinkaurelius.titan  @ line 1, column
>   1.    import static com.thinkaurelius.titan.core    ^
>
> 1 error

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you import a static method with `import static` rather than what appears to be a package?

Comment: Brilliant. No error now thanks to that and @albciff's answer. I removed 'static'.

Answer (score 1):

I never use the `titan` api, however looking at titan-core source on [github](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/tree/titan05/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core) the `com.thinkaurelius.titan.core` it's not a class, it's a package, so if you want to import all the classes in that package you have to use `.*`, also the `static` modifier imports the `static` members of the classes so if you want to use the classes not only the `static` members do:

```
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.*
```

Instead of:

```
import static com.thinkaurelius.titan.core
```

Alternatively if you want to import a specific class in this package, add it to the import, for example if you want to add `Titan` class:

```
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.Titan
```

For more information about `static` modifier you can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162187/what-does-the-static-modifier-after-import-mean).

Hope this helps,

Comment: Sounds closer but it didn't make the program run. How do you create an index without the API?

Comment: I just downloaded the jar and try `import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.*` without `static` and works without errors

Comment: @IanWarburton sorry I don't understand your comment. What did you mean?

Comment: You say you never use the API but as far as I can make out its needed in order to create indexes. So how would you make an index?

Comment: @IanWarburton sorry English  language it's not my strength... I just take a look on the `github` for the source code, download the zip with all jars, create a groovy script with your `import` and make a try to verify that not error is thrown, that`s all. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: Yes you have answered my question. But in your answer you said that you never use the API. How can you not use it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69853/discussion-between-albciff-and-ian-warburton).

Answer (score 0):

For any one as clueless as me this is what I have done:

1) Download Groovy 2) Create a text file. For example...

```
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.*
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.titan.*

TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.open("/Users/Ian/titan/conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties");

m = graph.getManagementSystem()

m.commit()

graph.shutdown()
```

You can see I have some class references to the API and I've connected to the database using the config file that was installed with the Titan distribution I downloaded from the website.

You need the `graph.shutdown()` else the console blocks. Although the documentation makes it sound like this shuts down the entire database. But it only seems to close the connection.

3) From the command line...

```
bin/groovy -cp  "../titan/lib/*" "../webstormprojects/myproject/titan.groovy"
```

The class path is set to the `lib` folder in my Titan instillation folder. The `*` includes all the packages.

And now hopefully I'm all set to add some indexes. Be aware that the Titan API has been through some significant changes so some of the online info is out of date. [This](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.3/upgrade.html) is quite helpful.

[Here](http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/javadoc/current/) is the latest documentation.