# Difference between import and static import?

Tags: java, import, static

What real (i.e. practical) difference between a normal import statment and static import statement?

```
import static java.lang.System.*;    
class StaticImportExample{  
  public static void main(String args[]){  

   out.println("Hello");
   out.println("Java");  

 }   
}  

import java.lang.System.*;    
class StaticImportExample{  
  public static void main(String args[]){  

   System.out.println("Hello"); 
   System.out.println("Java");  

 }   
}
```

Comment: [refer the following URL you will get the answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162187/what-does-the-static-modifier-after-import-mean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the "static" modifier after "import" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162187/what-does-the-static-modifier-after-import-mean)

Answer (score 6):

From java 5 onwards static import was introduced. Practically "import static" is used to reduce the number of keystrokes, which means that you need not to write the class name for a static member that you want to use.

As in your example, with `import static java.lang.System.*` you only need to write `out.println("Hello");` whereas normally you have to write `System.out.println("Hello");` i.e we have to write the class name(System) every time we need to call the static member(out) of it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @venkatesh's answer, it is worth pointing out the javadoc documentation about **when should static import be used?**

> So when should you use static import? **Very sparingly!** Only use it when
>   you'd otherwise be tempted to declare local copies of constants, or to
>   abuse inheritance (the Constant Interface Antipattern). In other
>   words, use it when you require frequent access to static members from
>   one or two classes. If you overuse the static import feature, it can
>   make your program unreadable and unmaintainable, polluting its
>   namespace with all the static members you import. Readers of your code
>   (including you, a few months after you wrote it) will not know which
>   class a static member comes from. Importing all of the static members
>   from a class can be particularly harmful to readability; if you need
>   only one or two members, import them individually. Used appropriately,
>   static import can make your program more readable, by removing the
>   boilerplate of repetition of class names.