# Can't import functions in java

Tags: java, importerror

I'm having a problem importing from a java class.

Here is my program:

```
import MyStuff.*;
public class Monday2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        p("\n\n\n\t\tGood Morning from the Morning2 Class.\n\n\n");
    }
}
```

Here is the MyStuff class:

```
public class MyStuff
{
    public static final void p(String inputString)
    {
        System.out.println(inputString);
    }
}
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: You haven't told what the problem is

Comment: Monday2.java:1: error: cannot find symbol
import static Stuff.*;
              ^
  symbol: class Stuff
Monday2.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        p("\n\n\n\t\tHello from Monday2 Program !\n\n\n");
        ^
  symbol:   method p(String)
  location: class Monday2
2 errors

Comment: I actually got this to work with Eclipse by exporting and importing the jar files etc. I'm having problems doing this from the command line. I guess I need to read up on the jar utility , my code is probably not creating my jar file.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot magic word - `static`, after your `import` like this

```
import static MyStuff.*;
```

You can read more in [appropriate topic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/static-import.html).
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `import MyStuff.*;` just use `import static MyStuff.p;` For more details please also see [What does the "static" modifier after "import" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162187/what-does-the-static-modifier-after-import-mean)