# Why i am unable to use Collectors in my code in java Stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
//import java.util.Collections;
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("abc", "", "bc", "efg", "abcd","", "jkl");
    List<String> filtered = strings.stream().filter(string -> !string.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

**output**

```
/tmp/java_tdo3eB/HelloWorld.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    List<String> filtered = strings.stream().filter(string -> !string.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
                                                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable Collectors
  location: class HelloWorld
 1 error
```

So i query is why i am unable to use Collectors as i have import that class also

Comment: You've imported the identifiers *within* Collections, `.*`.

Comment: Use `import java.util.stream.Collectors;`

Comment: The way you can use it with your current import i.e. [static import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162187/what-does-the-static-modifier-after-import-mean) is:

    `strings.stream().filter(string -> !string.isEmpty()).collect(toList());`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's your imports. Do them like this:

```
package experiments;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 *
 * @author Luc Talbot
 */
public class HelloWorld {

 public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("abc", "", "bc", "efg", "abcd","", "jkl");
    List<String> filtered = strings.stream()
                                   .filter(string -> !string.isEmpty())                        
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Output is:

run:
Hello World
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: @LukeTalbot  can u tell me doff b/w java.util.stream.Collectors and java.util.stream.Collectors.*.Why i use java.util.stream.Collectors.

Comment: Collectors is a class not a package. If Collectors was a package, Collectors.* would be all the classes in Collectors and your code would work. However Collectors.* is empty. You can tell that collector is a class because 1 - It begins with a capital letter. 2 - Your code calls the method .toList() from it. Collector is a class in the package stream. Don't forget to up click my answer - I'm a new contributor and can use the reputation points.

Comment: thank you very much @lucTalbot

Comment: done sir marked