# How to cast a String as an Array then dedupe Array in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, arrays, string

The core focus of this question is to **manipulate a string with comma delimiters and duplicate entries in Java so that it returns a deduped, comma delimited string** (all in one line and using native classes).

A.) Cast a comma delimited string as an Array,

B.) Dedupe that Array and then convert it back to a string

C.) Check against that newly deduped string to see how many unique entries there were, such that 1 commas means that there were 2 **original unique entries**.

D.) All of the above must be condensed into one line if possible. (If not, at least A and B is one line and C is its own line.

The following is a reference/picture of what is outlined above using JavaScript and jQuery.  It is only anecdotal.

Consider in jQuery the following code to convert a `string` into an `array` and then dedupe said `array` by first converting it to a `string` and then cast it as a `array` again in order to leverage a powerful `$.unique()` jQuery function.

```js
var daysProxyArray = "Monday,Monday,Friday,Friday".split(',');
daysProxyArray = $.unique(daysProxyArray.toString().split(','));
console.log(daysProxyArray.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Does anyone know how to do the equivalent in Java in one line where the end result is a string that I can count how many times a comma appears?  Such that, if 2 commas appear, I will know that 3 **unique** days were in the **original string**.

Comment: Java or Javascript?

Comment: @R4ncid in Java (native language for Talend program)  I gave JavaScript example just to explain the way I know how to do it and for reference.  Hoping someone with extension background in both languages find this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Arrays.stream("Monday,Monday,Friday,Friday".split(","))
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: Do I need to do an Java.import utils?  Will this work for any version of Java? Complete novice here (for Java).

Comment: Yup, you'll need to import 
`import java.util.Arrays;`

And you'll need Java 8 at least.

Comment: I also needed `import java.util.Arrays;` `import java.util.List;`and `import java.util.stream.Collectors`.  Found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53025721/5076162

Comment: oh sorry,  I wasn't really looking at `Collectors` and the return value. It was supported by the IDE most of the time ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count the amount of commas the following code should do the trick (in Java 8+):

```
String text = "Monday,Monday,Friday,Friday";
long numCommas = text.chars().filter(c -> c == ',').count();
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve in Java what you're doing in JQuery:

1. You first need to split the string and get an array of string with the split elements.
2. Then, pass the returned array to a `Set` in order to keep only the unique elements. Since a `Set` does not directly accept an array you first need to use the `asList` static method of the `Arrays` class.
3. Finally, either print the `Set` or get an array from the `Set` and print that.

```
//Splitting the string
String[] daysProxyArray = "Monday,Monday,Friday,Friday".split(",");

//Using a collection set to only keep the unique elements
Set<String> set = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(daysProxyArray));

//You could either print the set...
System.out.println(set);

//...Or returning the set's elements into an array and use that if you actually need an array
String[] res = new String[0];
res = set.toArray(res);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
```